# No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of `print' The type variable `a0' is ambiguous

Tags: haskell

```
data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]
flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
flatten (Elem element) = [element]
flatten (List []) = []
flatten (List (first:rest)) = flatten first ++ flatten (List (rest))
main = print $ flatten $ List []
```

I wrote the above seen code in haskell. When I execute this with any other parameter, for example

```
main = print $ flatten $ List [Elem 1, Elem 2]
main = print $ flatten $ Elem 1
```

It gives

```
[1, 2]
[1]
```

respectively.

It fails when I execute it with an empty List.

```
main = print $ flatten $ List []
```

**Error message**

```
No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of `print'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Show Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Show Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
  ...plus 23 others
In the expression: print
In the expression: print $ flatten $ List []
In an equation for `main': main = print $ flatten $ List []
```

**Questions**

1. Why does it fail and how can I fix this?
2. Should I change my `NestedList` definition to accept an empty `List`? If so, how do I do that. Its quite confusing.

Comment: GHC has no information which type to use. When you had `Elem 1`, in the list, that provided a `Num a` constraint, and then GHC could default the type variable to `Integer`. With no elements, it can't default the type variable `a0`. Give it a type signature, `main = print $ flatten $ (List [] :: NestedList () )`, for example, so the compiler knows which type to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the compiler can't know the type of `flatten $ List []`. Try to figure out the type yourself, you'll see it's `[a]` for some `a`, whilst `print` requires its argument to be an instance of `Show`, and `[a]` is an instance of `Show` if `a` is an instance of `Show`. Even though your list is empty, so there's no need for any constraint on `a` to represent `[]`, there's no way for the compiler to know.

As such, putting an explicit type annotation (for any type for which an instance of `Show` exists) should work:

```
main = print $ flatten $ List ([] :: [NestedList Int])
```

or

```
main = print $ flatten $ List ([] :: [NestedList ()])
```

or

```
main = print fl
  where
    fl :: [()]
    fl = flatten $ List []
```

Comment: What does the empty parens mean after `NestedList` and in `[()]`?

Comment: @thefourtheye `()` is a size-zero tuple. It's kind of Haskell's equivalent of `void`.

Comment: And haskell knows how to print an empty tuple?

Comment: Yes, since there's a 'Show' instance for '()'. Unlike '[]' which is of type '[a]', '()' is of type '()', so nothing can influence printing, the 'show' result is always '()'.

Answer (score 17):

The list type is polymorphic. Since you don't supply an element, just the empty list constructor `[]`, there's no way to infer what list type this is.

Is it:  `[] :: [Int]`

or `[] :: [Maybe (Either String Double)]`. Who's to say?

You are. Supply a type annotation to resolve the polymorphism, then GHC can dispatch to the correct show instance.

E.g.

```
main = print $ flatten $ List ([] :: [Int])
```

Answer (score 9):

To add to the answers here already, you may object "but what does it matter what type of things my list contains? it doesn't have any of them in it!"

Well, first of all, it is easy to construct situations in which it's unclear whether or not the list is empty, and anyway type checking hates to look at *values*, it only wants to look at *types*. This keeps things simpler, because it means that when it comes to deal with values, you can be sure you already know all the types.

Second of all, it actually *does* matter what kind of list it is, even if it's empty:

```
ghci> print ([] :: [Int])
[]
ghci> print ([] :: [Char])
""
```

Answer (score 3):

`[]` can be a list of floats, strings, booleans or actually any type at all. Thus, `print` does not know which instance of `show` to use.

Do as the error message says and give an explicit type, as in `([] :: [Int])`.